# MVC3 error message declared in my model isn't taking effect

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model, data-annotations

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "ONLY TYPE IN NUMBERS!")]
[Display(Name = "Telefono Fijo")]        
public int Telephone { get; set; }
```

Basically, I'd like that when someone types in a letter, that text up there should display.

Here's my view:

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RegisterModel.Telephone)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegisterModel.Telephone)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RegisterModel.Telephone)
</div>
```

When I type in letters, I get:

```
"The field Telefono Fijo must be a number."
```

And when I don't type in ANYTHING, I get:

```
"ONLY TYPE IN NUMBERS!"
```

Any ideas? I only want the custom message to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [RegularExpressionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx):

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+$", ErrorMessage = "ONLY TYPE IN NUMBERS!")]
```